# Modifying a static method to add two counters when comparing arrays using for loops in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, static-methods

Using this segment of code I already have, I want to modify the selectionSort method to have two counters, one for the number of comparisons, and one for the number of data swaps. Each time two data elements are compared (regardless of whether the items are in the correct order—we're interested in that a comparison is being done at all), increment the comparison counter.  Each time two data items are actually swapped, increment the data swap counter.

So far this is what I have tried to add the counters. However, I receive an error "Unresolved compilation problem: counter cannot be resolved to a variable".

```
public static void selectionSort(double[] list) {
      for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
      // Find the minimum in the list[i..list.length-1]
      double currentMin = list[i];
      int currentMinIndex = i;
      int counter = 0;

      for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
        if (currentMin > list[j]) {
          currentMin = list[j];
          currentMinIndex = j;
        }
      }

      // Swap list[i] with list[currentMinIndex] if necessary;
      if (currentMinIndex != i) {
        list[currentMinIndex] = list[i];
        list[i] = currentMin;
      }
      counter += 1;
    }

      System.out.println("The size of the sorted array is " + list.length + " and the count is " + counter);
  }
```

I have the main method prepared below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      final int NUM_ELEMENTS = 10;

      double[] lo2Hi = new double[NUM_ELEMENTS];
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
          lo2Hi[i] = i + 1;
      }
      selectionSort(lo2Hi);
      double[] hi2Lo = new double[NUM_ELEMENTS];
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
          hi2Lo[i] = 10 - i;
      }
      selectionSort(hi2Lo);
      double[] random = new double[NUM_ELEMENTS];
      for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
          random[i] = Math.random();
      }
      selectionSort(random);
  }
```

Comment: What did you try? Printing the counters should be the same as printing the size.

Comment: I tried `int counter = 0;` in the outer for loop in the static method, added `counter +=1` and tried printing the value but it shows an error.

Comment: Your question asks "how to print the counters?" but it sounds like you are still struggling to add the counting logic the first place. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried and explain what happens. If you get an error message, show it. If not, show the output you get and explain what you want it to be instead.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated my post.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `println()` at the end of `selectionSort()` is trying to acces the variable `counter`, but `counter` is "out of scope" at that point. Variables only exist within the pair of `{}`'s they were declared inside (that's what "scope" is).

Move the `int counter = 0;` statement out of the `for` loop, and put it at top of the method. Then it will be in-scope for the print statement.